# exporting outputs in cloudformation using custom resources with lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I ran a CFN template using custom resources to export route53 private hosted zone name. I was able to export the hostedzonename as I wanted but I can not import this hostedzonename into another stack.
I get this error:

```
Value of property HostedZoneName must be of type String
```

Any help is appreciated. thank you.
here is my code.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: CloudFormation exports


Resources:
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: root
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - "logs:CreateLogGroup"
            - "logs:CreateLogStream"
            - "logs:PutLogEvents"
            - "route53:Get*"
            - "route53:List*"
            - "route53:TestDNSAnswer"
            Resource: "*"
  GetCertARN: 
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    DependsOn:
      - LambdaExecutionRole
    Properties: 
      Handler: "index.handler"
      Role: 
        Fn::GetAtt: 
          - "LambdaExecutionRole"
          - "Arn"
      Runtime: "python3.7"
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 100
      Code: 
        ZipFile: |
          import boto3
          import botocore
          import cfnresponse
          route53 = boto3.client('route53')
          def handler(event, context):
            hostedZoneName=''
            response2 = route53.list_hosted_zones()
            f=response2['HostedZones']
            for zone in f:
                config=zone["Config"]
                name=zone["Name"]
                e=config["PrivateZone"]
                if ('abcxyz.cloud' in name) and e:
                    hostedZoneName=name
            responseData = {}
            responseData['hostedzonename'] = hostedZoneName
            cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData)
  CertArnInvocation:
    Type: Custom::CertArn
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt GetCertARN.Arn
      Region: !Ref "AWS::Region"

Outputs:
  ExportsStackName:
    Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
    Export:
      Name: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}'

  HostedZoneNameOutput: 
    Value: !GetAtt CertArnInvocation.hostedzonename
    Description: Return Value of private hosted zone name
    Export: 
      Name: !Sub 'nonProdHostedZoneName'
```

Comment: I ended up deleting the line where I declared hostedZoneName= ' '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting `HostedZoneNameOutput` under name of `nonProdHostedZoneName`:

```
    Export: 
      Name: !Sub 'nonProdHostedZoneName'
```

But it seams that you are importing (not-shown) value called `HostedZoneName`.

Update based on comments (`HostedZoneName` was list, not string). Corrected version:

```
HostedZoneName: !ImportValue nonProdHostedZoneName
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, this is how I'm importing it.
HostedZoneName: 
                - Fn::ImportValue:
                      Fn::Sub: nonProdHostedZoneName

Comment: @eshmetchishik Hi, you don't need ` Fn::Sub: ` when importing and exporting. None of the templates you posted has `HostedZoneName` as in the error message. Where does it come from?

Comment: it is coming from 
myDNSRecord2:
  Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
  Properties:
    HostedZoneName: example.com.
    Name: mysite.example.com.
    Type: A
    TTL: '900'
    ResourceRecords:
    - 192.168.0.1
    - 192.168.0.2
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-route53.html

Comment: @eshmetchishik I see. You use list for `HostedZoneName` (note `-`), not string. I updated the answer.